# Remove elements from df1 that appear in df2

Tags: r

I am trying to us `quantmod::getSymbols` and `quantmod::getEarningsCalendar` to remove all the days when earnings were reported for given stocks, which I input and loop through.

I've tried to use the `match` and `grep` functions, but haven't been successful.

For example with:

```
ticker <- c("MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT")
date <- c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-02")
df1 = data.frame(date,ticker)
df1
        date ticker
1 2016-01-01   MSFT
2 2016-01-01   MSFT
3 2016-01-02   MSFT

ticker <- c("AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT")
date <- c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-02")
df2 = data.frame(date,ticker)
df2
     date ticker
1 2016-01-01   AAPL
2 2016-01-02   GOOG
3 2016-01-02   MSFT
```

I would like to remove the third row in `df1`, because it also appears in `df2`, and get:

```
      date ticker
1 2016-01-01   MSFT
2 2016-01-01   MSFT
```

Using `pmatch` I came up with this:

```
library(dplyr)
ticker.matches <- as.data.frame(pmatch(df1$ticker, df2$ticker, nomatch = NA_integer_, duplicates.ok = FALSE))
date.matches <- as.data.frame(pmatch(df1$date, df2$date, nomatch = NA_integer_, duplicates.ok = FALSE))
results.df <- bind_cols(df1, ticker.matches, date.matches)
colnames(results.df) <- c("date", "ticker", "ticker.match", "date.match")
results.df[is.na(results.df)] <- 0
my.attempt <- subset(results.df, date.match != ticker.match)
```

Which was admittedly very sloppy, but seemed to work, until I realized it can't handle repeats. 
Note that df1 and df will most likely be different lengths, and that df1 will have additional columns of unrelated data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go,

```
df1[!(apply(df1, 1, toString) %in% apply(df2, 1, toString)), ]
#         date ticker
# 1 2016-01-01   MSFT
# 2 2016-01-01   MSFT
```

If you have "columns of unrelated data" you can use `[1:2]`, as

```
 df1[!(apply(df1[1:2], 1, toString) %in% apply(df2[1:2], 1, toString)), ]
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you. Is there a way I could remove the day before and the day after as well? I realized that that would be ideal for what I'm doing. E.g: if there is a match on `2016-01-02` between df1 and df2, then `2016-01-01`, `2016-01-02`, and `2016-01-03` would be removed from df1(if they exist in df1, which they may not because of previous filters).

Comment: Better to close this question and ask your new one in a separate thread where you show [a specific problem, the shortest code necessary to reproduce, and the desired behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` solution.  I created the data frames with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` as you may run into issues unless you specify the factor consistently between both data frames.

```
ticker <- c("MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT")
date <- c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-02")
df1 = data.frame(date,ticker, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1

ticker <- c("AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT")
date <- c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-02")
df2 = data.frame(date,ticker, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2

df1 %>% filter( ! ((date == df2$date) & (ticker == df2$ticker)) )

#        date ticker
#1 2016-01-01   MSFT
#2 2016-01-01   MSFT
```

**EDIT**

Another possibility is to use `anti_join` in `dplyr`

```
df1 %>% anti_join(df2, by = c('date'='date', 'ticker'='ticker'))
```

This returns keys in table df1 that are not in table df2, joining on the `by=` (two columns in this case).

Comment: Good solution too, thank you! If you have any ideas on the comment I posted in the above I'd love to hear from you as well.

Comment: @RyGuy I will have to think about the question in the comment.  I agree it should be made into a separate question, I think it will make what you are asking a little more clear.